How to show tickmarks when using whitegrid seaborn style
I'm struggling to find how to show the tick marks on the x-axis when I enable the whitegrid seaborn style:
import datetime
import itertools
import random

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

chronos = np.arange('2024-03-01', '2024-07-01',  dtype='datetime64[D]')

with sns.axes_style("whitegrid"):
    sns.set({'xtick.bottom': True, 'xtick.top': True, 'patch.edgecolor': 'b'})
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 4), layout='constrained')
    sns.barplot(    
        x=chronos, 
        y=[random.randint(0, 10) for _ in chronos],
        ax=ax,
        width=1,
    )
    ax.tick_params(
        axis='x', 
        rotation=30
    )
    ax.tick_params(axis="both", colors="black")
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(
        mdates.MonthLocator(
            interval=1, 
            bymonthday=1
        )
    )



Without the style applied, the marks appear. I've looked at the docs but can't figure out which option is removing them.
How do i show the tick marks with the seaborn style enabled?

Unfortunately, no.

ax.tick_params(bottom=True, left=True) should work

That works, thank you.
